# Do While loop keeps terminating and setting values to 0

Tags: arrays, excel, while-loop, do-while, vba

I'm going crazy with this. I have a basic block of code in one of my excel vba modules that keeps terminating early and upon using break lines, i find that all my inner values are being reset to 0.

My goal:

1. check if (bottom_cell + once_cell_up) > (bottom_cell)
2. if so, perform (bottom_cell).Value + (bottom_cell + one_cell_up).Value
3. assign this result in (bottom_cell).Value
4. if not, increase one_cell_up value by one and repeat process until 
          cell with larger value is found

This is the basic jist. I have some safeguards in the block for if all values above the current value are less than it, once the for loop loops to the end, etc.

After running my code, diff_value, upcol, and upcol_maxflag are all 0, mysteriously. p is 51.

Code and variable definitions are below:

upcol - up column counter; increases if above cell value isn't larger
filled_col - string array of cell addresses
filled_collen - length of filled_col array (it's a 1D array)
upcol_maxflag - for use if, after going through all cells above the current
                index cell, none are larger and thus it'll break out of the
                loop for the next index

Excel VBA code (Excel 2013):

```
Dim p As Integer
Dim diff_value As Double
Dim upcol As Integer
Dim upcol_maxflag As Integer
For p = (filled_collen - 1) To 1
    diff_value = 1
    upcol = 1
    upcol_maxflag = 0
    Do While diff_value > 0
        diff_value = Range(filled_col(p)).Value - _
                     Range(filled_col(p - upcol)).Value
        If Val((Range(filled_col(p)).Value) > _
           Val(Range(filled_col(p - upcol)).Value)) Then
            upcol = upcol + 1
        End If
        If (upcol = p) And (p <> 1) Then
            upcol_maxflag = 1
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    If (upcol_maxflag <> 1) Then
        Range(filled_col(p)).Value = Range(filled_col(p)).Value _
        + Range(filled_col(p - upcol)).Value
    End If
Next
```

---

Thanks to anyone that can figure out what's going on here. I feel like I had a decent grasp on excel VBA but this is kicking my butt.

Comment: `For p = (filled_collen - 1) To 1` Should have `Step -1` after it. I think it will work if you do that :)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I didn't realize when stepping through backwards that extra bit of info was necessary. Thank you!!